# Would have gotten loose(rope)

Tags: verbs

Let's say you are watching an *Indiana Jones* movie, wherein *Indiana Jones* would have died if the rope was unloosen during a cliff climbing scene, which was a life-and-death situation. Can you say:

> Oh! He would have been dead by now, if the rope was **unloosen**.

- (after reading the corrections) Oh! He would have been dead by now, if the rope had come loose.
- Oh! He would have been dead by now, if the rope was loosened.

Or

> If the rope would **have gotten loose**, he will probably die.

- (''Have'' changed into ''had'') If the rope **had gotten loose**, he will probably  die.

I am not sure if I correctly used the verb **loose**, are they both correct?

Comment: "if the rope was unloosen" is not correct for a couple reasons.  Firstly, *loosen* means "become loose", so "unloosen" would actually mean "become tight"!  Also, you're using the passive voice in *the rope was ____*, but the passive voice requires the past participle, which would be loosen**ed**.

Comment: In AmE unloosen: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unloosen but it would not be used here for a rope.

Comment: @stangdon - Counterintuitively enough, _unloosen_ is synonymous with _loosen_.

Comment: "...had gotten loose" is not a good choice.  That phrase is usually used when someone (or some animal) escapes captivity: it's not appropriate for an inanimate object like a rope.  You'd use it in a sentence like, "It was good you closed the front door because otherwise the cat could have gotten loose and run into the street."

Comment: @J.R.- true that; "York, unloose your long imprison'd thoughts, And let thy tongue be equal with thy heart" - but I've never heard *unloosened* used that way.

Answer (score 5):

If the rope had come loose, he would have died.

If the rope had come untied, he would have died.

If the rope had become untethered, he would have died.

A rope **comes loose** when it is tethered (secured) by a piton to a rock or tied around a rock and then comes undone where it is anchored. It becomes untethered.

**A rope is loosened**, when you are tied up by a bad guy (for example), and the bad guy makes the rope tying you up, looser, not so tight.

Comment: The last 2 sentences in your answer seems illogical, ''a rope **comes loose** when it is unthethered''( I think this is what you mean) also, **A rope is loosened** when you are not tied up properly by a bad guy...

Comment: Do we realy use ''come loose', instead of ''become loose''?

Comment: Yes, we do say come loose: the boat came loose from its moorings. You will see examples: mountain climbing + rope came loose. A rope is not loosened when you are tied up by a bad guy. A bad guy can loosen the ropes tied around your hands and feet. And people often loosen their belts when the belt is too tight.

Comment: For the record: loosen means that a thing is held less tightly than before: ***loosen one's grip on something; loosen a rope, loosen a necktie, loosen the strings [puppets], to loosen restrictions***, loosen bonds to a community, etc. The thing is still held by something else but not so tightly or tautly as before.

Comment: I believe it is **prusik** not **prussick** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prusik

Answer (score 2):

*Loosen* is an unusual word, in that *loosen* and *unloose* are synonyms, even though they look like they might be antonyms.

Two verbs you can use in your scenario are *to [loosen](https://onelook.com/?w=loosen&ls=a)* or *to [unloose](https://onelook.com/?w=unloose&ls=a)*. Again, even though they appear like they are antonymns, they can be used synonymously:

> When he comes home from work, Ted **loosens** his tie.
>
> When he comes home from work, Ted **unlooses** his tie.

To make matters even more confusing, the word *[loose](https://onelook.com/?w=loose&ls=a)* can be used as a verb or as an adjective.

So, you could write your sentences in many ways, including:

> He would have died if the rope **was unloosed**.
>
> He would have died if the rope **had loosened**.
>
> If the rope **had loosed**, he probably would have died.
>
> If the rope had **become loose**, he probably would have died.

---

Quick definitions (all adapted from Macmillan, taken from [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com)):

- **unloose** (*v.*) to untie something, or to make it looser
- **loosen** (*v.*) to become or make something less tightly fastened or less firmly fixed
- **loose** (*v.*) to become or make loose, looser, or less tight
- **loose** (*adj.*) not firmly fixed or tied

Comment: Got them all, but one last thing, can we say ''He would **have** died if the rope **was** unloosed.'' I think stangdon is correct coz' it is not a parallel sentence specifically the active-passive form kind of thing.

Comment: A climbing rope could be loosened without causing a person to fall off a mountain. In fact, climbers often loosen or tighten ropes.

Comment: @Lambie - What you say is quite true, but the OP has indicated in the question that they are asking about using the verb _loosen_ correctly. Ergo, my answer focuses more on grammar than  mountaineering.

Comment: He did say it was a "cliff-climbing" scene and the guy could have died. That's why I changed it to another verb.

Comment: @L - He did say he wanted to learn more about the verb _loosen_. That's why I included examples with a necktie.